# Error while posting data to webmethods through HTTPS URL

Tags: xml, ssl, post, https, webmethods

When i try to POST data through https url, I am getitng this error "Outer Exception Sending (POST/PUT) 58C191DE-D9C6-42f3-90A1-23CD2F08F585 to Server xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx exception message: Handler did not return a response message".
The same data i am able to post through http url. Please let me know where to debug this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the Log-Level (Settings > Logging > Edit Server Logger Details) in the Integration Server 0038,39,40,64 and then run again and post the Results, to get more Informations for Debugging